# Why does Grub2 break EVERY time I update my laptop?

Tags: boot, grub2, updates, raid

I'm running Ubuntu 11.04. I just don't understand it. It doesn't matter if it is a kernel upgrade, or an Adobe Flash update. The next time I restart my computer Grub2 breaks. All I get is a blinking "_". Then I have to boot into a live CD, mount my FS, run

`sudo grub-setup -d /media/FS_NAME_HERE/boot/grub /dev/mapper/isw_blah_blah_blah`

and then restart, then run

`sudo update-grub`.

- It only happens when there is an update. Because if I don't run anything, and I make sure to run sudo `update-grub` after I reinstall it then I can restart as many times as I want--but only until I update something else.
- I'm 70% sure everything still works after I install something new. If it'll help I'm running a Sony Vaio Z. There are 2 solid state chips on board that are in a raid0 array. I've never had this problem before I just switched back to Ubuntu.

Comment: Are you sure it only happens when you update something, not everytime you restart?

Comment: Positive. Because if I don't run anything, _and_ I make sure to run `sudo update-grub` after I reinstall it then I can restart as many times as I want--but only until I update something else.

Comment: Hmm, what about installing programs, not just updating? Or even just saving new files (a text document, e.g.) to your disk? Given the vast number of things that updates can change, I suspect that changes to your FS are causing GRUB to drop it. It's possible there's an issue with your RAID syncing after you make changes.

Comment: saving files works fine. I can still restart after that. I'm 70% sure everything still works after I install something new. If it'll help I'm running a Sony Vaio Z. There are 2 solid state chips on board that are in a raid0 array. I've never had this problem before I just switched back to Ubuntu.

Comment: Turns out that saving files breaks it as well. Don't bother with it anymore though. I'm switching back to Arch.

Comment: Heh, okay, sounds good. Be sure to post here if you ever find the solution.

Comment: Please post the results of Bootscript so that we can see the details of your current grub and disk setup.  Also, can you confirm you have forced a fsck (`sudo shutdown -rF now`) on your disks: http://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/

Comment: Are you by any chance using a Wubi installation? This is very common with Wubi however it should only happen after a Kernel upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes when the system is updated, it configures grub again. As I could see, you use a RAID array. You have to reinstall grub in the MBR of your array. That done, I don't think you will keep having this problem. Try BootRepair:

http://www.webupd8.org/2011/06/boot-repair-fix-ubuntu-boot-issues.html

Answer (score -1):

or, you just try something else [ trust me ist's even better ]

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LightDM

Comment: what has LightDM got to do with Grub2?

Comment: well, if its an annoying problem like that, why shouldn't you consider changin your DM ?
but i see that my post wasn't right here, it was just a quick thought. i'm sorry.