# Grub breaks at each update

Tags: boot, grub2, 16.04

I have a really really weird boot issue and would like to share with you to see if some of you already encountered it. I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 on my (not so recent) Asus eeePC 1215B. It's the first time I scratch Windows on this machine.

Each time I perform an upgrade, even simple ones that do not involve a kernel upgrade, Grub breaks. The next time I reboot, I just get a blinking cursor and I have to boot on live CD and reinstall Grub (with Boot Repair or even simply with chroot and doing apt-get --reinstall grub-pc).

I have absolutely no clue why this happening but it's really annoying. I have done a full reinstall, problem persists.

The laptop has a single disk, partitioned in MSDOS. Linux installed on primary bootable partition. Strange thing is that the BIOS let me boot the USB key either in EFI mode or legacy. However, it seems the hard disk boots only in legacy mode. I tried to create an EFI partition and install grub efi but never managed to make it boot. Of course no option in the BIOS to select the boot type (apart from external drive where it lets me choose!!). I don't know if it could be linked to that. Anyway I clearly have the grub MBR version installed and I made sure to install from a live CD booted in legacy mode as well.

Also, Asus created a 16MB primary partition with ESP flags that looks not formatted. I googled a bit and found that this in fact a FAT16 partition used for a special fast boot mode. I scratched it to make sure it's not coming from that.

Any clue ?? Help is more than welcome because I'm kinda stuck.

FYI I found this very old post where someone describes the same symptom, but no answer: [Why does Grub2 break EVERY time I update my laptop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58753/why-does-grub2-break-every-time-i-update-my-laptop)

Comment: After a bit more digging, I found that it's not related to updates at all... I thought it was correlated because I often reboot after updates. But it occurred also without any update.

I found this interesting thread on Arch forum that comes with a more satisfying explanation: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=134961
It seems problem would be correlated to suspend mode. Someone suggests to try with acpi=noirq so I will give a try...